# Join subquery with doctrine and Symfony 2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I saw the begining of an answer in a post about Zend : [Join subquery with doctrine 2 DBAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768821/join-subquery-with-doctrine-2-dbal/37726068#37726068)
Unfortunately I can't manage it to work. I tried aimfeld soltuion like that:

```
$qbaudio = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $subSelect = $qbaudio->select ('a.id_support id_support','sum(a.duration) dureeTotale','count(a) nbAudio')
        ->from('MyBundle:AudioObject','a')
        ->groupBy('a.id_support')
        ->where('a.type = :audio_type')
        ->getQuery();
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('sp.ref1','sp.title1','count(i) nbImage','sp.nbSupportSaisi','sum(a.duration) dureeTotale','count(a) nbAudio','a.sampling')
      ->from('MyBundle:Storage', 'st')
            ->leftJoin('p.sides','si')
            ->leftJoin('si.support','sp')
            ->leftJoin('sp.images','i')
            ->leftJoin('sp.audioObjects', sprintf('(%s)',$subSelect->getDQL()), 'a', 'ON sp.id = a.id_support')
            ->groupBy('sp.id')
            ->setParameter('audio_type', 'MP3')
```

Unfortunately I got this message :

```
Error: Expected end of string, got 'SELECT'
```

If it's possible with ZEnd, Why not with Symfony?
Any idea? 
Thanks

Comment: Look closely.  Can you spot the difference between getSQL and getDQL?

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL instead of DQL:

```
$subSelect->getSQL()
```