# QueryBuilder - Use Select in an innerJoin

Tags: symfony, query-builder

can someone help me.
I need to change my sql query to a querybuilder. I don't know how to use select inside a innerJoin.

Here my sql query:

```sql
SELECT 
      user.id,
      analytic_youtube_demographic.age_group, 
      analytic_youtube_demographic.percentage
FROM 
    user
INNER JOIN user_youtube ON user_youtube.id = user.id
INNER JOIN analytic ON analytic.id = user_youtube.analytic_id
INNER JOIN analytic_youtube_demographic ON analytic_youtube_demographic.analytic_id = analytic.id
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT analytic_youtube_demographic.id as id, MAX(analytic_youtube_demographic.percentage) max
from user
INNER JOIN user_youtube ON user_youtube.id = user.id
INNER JOIN analytic ON analytic.id = user_youtube.analytic_id
INNER JOIN analytic_youtube_demographic ON analytic_youtube_demographic.analytic_id = analytic.id
GROUP BY user.id
) AS T ON analytic_youtube_demographic.percentage = T.max
WHERE analytic_youtube_demographic.age_group IN ('18-24')
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Please provide what you have so far (and entities code, if possible)...

Comment: You need to include entities definitions for these tables involved in your query

Comment: DQL is not really made for this. You can have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768821/join-subquery-with-doctrine-2-dbal