# Doctrine query builder inner join with subselect

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have this query in SQL that's working fine:

```
SELECT tl.*
FROM table1 tl
INNER JOIN table2 tl2
ON tl.id = tl2.other_id
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT other_id, MAX(date) maxDATE
   FROM table2
   GROUP BY other_id
) 
tlv2 ON tl2.other_id = tlv2.other_id AND
tl2.date = tlv2.maxDATE WHERE tl.access=0
ORDER BY tlv2.maxDATE DESC
```

Now the problem is, I cant seem to figure out how to translate this into the Doctrine query builer.

I have this:

```
$subquery = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(Table2::class)
    ->createQueryBuilder('tl2')
    ->select(array('other_id','MAX(date) maxDate'))
    ->groupBy('other_id')
    ->getDQL();
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('tl');
    $qb->select('tl')
       ->innerJoin(Table2::class,'tl2','WITH','tl.id = tl2.other_id')
       ->innerJoin("(".$subquery.")",'tlv2','WITH','tl2.date = tlv2.maxDATE')
       ->where('tl.access = 0')
       ->orderBy('tlv2.maxDATE','DESC');
```

but it's giving me the error:

`Subquery is not supported here`

On the line where I put the `$subquery` variable.

I cant seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/3542#issuecomment-162364183) if you are using the ORM then the mapping will fail, you can only run this without hydration, in case you are using the DBAL only it [will work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768821/join-subquery-with-doctrine-2-dbal/35656904#35656904) as you expect

If you would go for native query solution and still need a mapped result then you can use `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::createNativeQuery` with `\Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping`

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT tl.*
    FROM table1 tl
    INNER JOIN table2 tl2
    ON tl.id = tl2.other_id
    INNER JOIN
    (
       SELECT other_id, MAX(date) maxDATE
       FROM table2
       GROUP BY other_id
    ) 
    tlv2 ON tl2.other_id = tlv2.other_id AND
    tl2.date = tlv2.maxDATE WHERE tl.access=0
    ORDER BY tlv2.maxDATE DESC
SQL;


$rsm = new Query\ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult(Entity::class, 'e');
$rsm->addFieldResult('e','id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('e','date', 'createAt');

$result = $this->entityManager->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)->getResult();
```