# Joining 2 results in Doctrine throws error

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql, doctrine-query

I am trying to JOIN 2 queries in `DQL` but I am getting an error which says,

`[Semantical Error] line 0, col 114 near '(select u.email': Error: Class '(' is not defined.`
I have gone through  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600439/error-in-nested-subquery-in-dql-class-is-not-defined. But  I could not figure out. Please help.
My Query is as follows:

```
     $filterQuery = "SELECT tempResult1.email as email,tempResult1.name as name , tempResult1.id as user 
                    FROM (select u.email as email,a.name as name , u.id as user
                    FROM
                        Application\Entity\Userhasrole  uhr 
                        INNER JOIN 
                        Application\Entity\Oauthrole r with uhr.applicationrole = r.id
                        INNER JOIN
                        Application\Entity\Application a with r.application = a.id
                        INNER JOIN
                        Application\Entity\Oauthusers u 
                       
                    ) tempResult1
                    LEFT JOIN 
                    (SELECT uhr1.user as user  FROM Application\Entity\Userhasrole  uhr1 where 
                      a.id = :applicationId
                    ) tempResult2
                    with tempResult1.user = tempResult2.user";
    $queryObject = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery($filterQuery);
    $queryObject->setParameter('applicationId', $applicationId);
    $result = $queryObject->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

You mix 2 concepts of Doctrine2 :

- using SQL
- using DQL

If you want to achieve that you want, build tables selections, and not entities selections, you should use `EntityManager::createNativeQuery()` method and set an SQL query as parameter.

`EntityManager::createQuery()` is used only for DQL queries